# Having trouble with saving graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

esteemed colleagues. I am experiencing an issue I have encountered when attempting to store graphical illustrations via Mathematica version 11. Upon a right-click on my generated three-dimensional plot (or the selected area situated in the right-hand corner), the system behaves expectedly, allowing me to designate the desired file format, directory location, and file name to be used. However, as soon as I confirm my selections by clicking the 'Save' button, the dialogue box abruptly closes, and after a short pause, the Mathematica application malfunctions entirely, and terminates itself. This happens whilst my codes are running on a 'Script' (i.e., .wls) file format.

Comment: Type Export Script into the search bar at the top of mathematica.stackexchange.com and tap <Enter> and read through some of the questions and answers about trying to use Export from within scripting. Maybe that will find you a solution that doesn't fail. If not then that might provide additional clues for someone to suggest other tests.